# Insert avoiding duplicates but without using primary keys

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I have a table with 2 fields which are NOT primary keys, and they cannot be as I do have duplicates.
I want to insert data from a joined table, but avoiding more duplicates. What I did is:

```
insert into X(A,B)
select *
from (Y.A, Z.B
    from Y join Z
    on (Y.id = Z.id)) tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM X
        WHERE A = tmp.A
        AND B = tmp.B)
```

As I understood it is best not to use INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS, do you think there are possible problems with this kind of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using MERGE Query

MERGE X AS TARGET
USING (SELECT Y.A AS A, Z.B AS B FROM Y INNER JOIN Z ON Y.Id = Z.Id) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.A = SOURCE.A AND TARGET.B = SOURCE.B
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT VALUES (SOURCE.A, SOURCE.B)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590085/Merge-in-SQL-Server-2008
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/